# "She sees in the mirror" vs. "she will see in the mirror?"

Tags: tenses, future

Is this sentence correct?

> She will grow up hating what she sees in the mirror.

Or should it be:

> She will grow up hating what she will see in the mirror.

I think first one is correct, I just want to know why and the rule.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage! You may be interested in our companion site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Please read our [about] page to see what kinds of questions are on topic here.

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference for ELU, but it would have been okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical, and the choice between the two depends on the context. The first is more likely, because here the present tense, *sees*, refers to something that will happen repeatedly over a period of time.